# How does R use categorical variables in regression

Tags: r

How does R treat categorical/factor variable in a regression setting? Does is just perfom (some kind of) one-hot encoding or..?

Answer (score 1):

If there are `k` levels for the categorical variable, it automatically treats it as `k-1` dummy binary variables, indicating levels `1` to `k-1` of the variable.

This is due to multicollinearity: should we decompose it to `k`dummy vars, then the sum of these vars in each row is exactly 1, which is the intercept value. If you choose to run a regression model without intercept (i.e `lm(y~x-1)`, it'll decompose into `k` variables.